# Is there an alternative to allowsTransparency in iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, swift, sprite-kit, skview

I have a SKView with the following code

```
allowsTransparency = true
```

that it works correctly in iOS 8.0. The problem is... is only available to iOS 8.0 and later.

What can I use in iOS 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Transparency depends on how `SKView` sets up its OpenGL ES framebuffer. You can't make it set up for transparency in iOS 7 because there's no API to.

However, depending on why you want transparency, there may be an iOS 7 alternative. For example, many have sought to use a transparent `SKView` to add particle effects to what's otherwise a UIKit app — not knowing that there's long been an API to do that in `CAEmitterLayer`.